# How should I configure the ADC of an injected channel with PWM for STM32 microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, adc, pwm, embedded, keil

I am trying to configure the ADC injected channel with PWM using STM32F103C8T6 but I don't know how to configure the ADC injected channel with PWM.

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean by "ADC injected channel"?  Can you cite pin numbers?  What do you mean by "with PWM"?  Usually one uses continuous voltages with ADCs, not PWM.  Please _edit your question_ to tell us what you're _really_ trying to do (i.e., where does the PWM come from, what does it mean, why do you want to A/D convert it) -- then maybe we can help.

Comment: Did you look at registers ADC_CR2, ADC_JSQR  and  ADC_CR1 from the reference manual (https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f103c8.html#) as well as section 11.3.9/11.9.1/Figure 22 ? Also, I guess you mean PWM is the trigger source?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes I saw the registers ADC_CR2, ADC_JSQR and ADC_CR1 from the reference manual and yes i trigger the PWM.

Comment: @SudhakarR - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was a reply to other comments, so it has been converted into a comment as well. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself & don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more information / clarification, please [edit] the question (or write a comment, for minor responses to comments). || Please see the [tour] & [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the ADC-injected channel with PWM on an STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller, you will need to follow these steps:

1. Enable the injected conversion mode by setting the JEOS (JEOC
   Interrupt Enable for Injected Channels) and JEN (Injected Conversion
   Enable) bits in the ADC_CR1 register.
2. Configure the trigger source for the injected conversion by setting
   the JEXTSEL (Injected External Trigger Selection) bits in the
   ADC_CR2 register. The trigger source can be a timer, an external
   event, or a software trigger.
3. Configure the injected channel sequence by setting the JL (Injected
   Sequence Length) and JSQ (Injected Channel Sequence) bits in the
   ADC_JSQR register. The injected channel sequence defines the order
   in which the injected channels will be converted.
4. Enable the ADC interrupt by setting the JEOCIE (JEOC Interrupt
   Enable) bit in the ADC_CR1 register.
5. Configure the PWM output for the desired channel by setting the
   appropriate bits in the TIM_CCMRx registers.
6. Configure the PWM output compare mode by setting the appropriate
   bits in the TIM_CCER register.
7. Enable the PWM output by setting the CCxE (Capture/Compare x Output
   Enable) bit in the TIM_CCER register.
8. Start the PWM by setting the CEN (Counter Enable) bit in the TIM_CR1
   register.

It is important to note that these steps are just a general outline and may vary depending on your specific application. It is recommended to refer to the STM32F103C8T6 datasheet and reference manual for more detailed information on configuring the ADC and PWM peripherals.

---

You can use the code below to configure the ADC-injected channel with PWM on an STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

// define PWM output pin
#define PWM_OUTPUT_PIN GPIO_Pin_6
#define PWM_OUTPUT_PORT GPIOA

// define ADC injected channel
#define ADC_INJECTED_CHANNEL ADC_Channel_3

// define timer period and prescaler
#define TIMER_PERIOD 1000
#define TIMER_PRESCALER 7200

// initialize ADC and PWM
void init_ADC_PWM(void)
{
  // enable clock for ADC and GPIOA
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1 | RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
  // enable clock for timer 2
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

  // configure PWM output pin
  GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_init;
  gpio_init.GPIO_Pin = PWM_OUTPUT_PIN;
  gpio_init.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
  gpio_init.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(PWM_OUTPUT_PORT, &gpio_init);

  // configure ADC
  ADC_InitTypeDef adc_init;
  adc_init.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_InjecSimult;
  adc_init.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  adc_init.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  adc_init.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T2_CC1;
  adc_init.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
  adc_init.ADC_NbrOfChannel = 1;
  ADC_Init(ADC1, &adc_init);

  // configure injected channel sequence
  ADC_InjectedSequencerLengthConfig(ADC1, 1);
  ADC_InjectedChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_INJECTED_CHANNEL, 1, ADC_SampleTime_1Cycles5);

  // enable ADC injected conversion
  ADC_ExternalTrigInjectedConvConfig(ADC1, ADC_ExternalTrigInjecConv_T2_CC1);
  ADC_AutoInjectedConvCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

  // enable ADC injected channel interrupt
  ADC_ITConfig(ADC1, ADC_IT_JEOC, ENABLE);

  // enable ADC
  ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

  // enable ADC calibration
  ADC_ResetCalibration(ADC1);
  while(ADC_GetResetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
  ADC_StartCalibration(ADC1);
  while(ADC_GetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));

  // configure timer 2
  TIM_TimeBase

TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef tim_init;
  tim_init.TIM_Period = TIMER_PERIOD - 1;
  tim_init.TIM_Prescaler = TIMER_PRESCALER - 1;
  tim_init.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
  tim_init.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
  TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &tim_init);

  // configure PWM output compare mode
  TIM_OCInitTypeDef tim_oc_init;
  tim_oc_init.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
  tim_oc_init.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
  tim_oc_init.TIM_Pulse = 500; // 50% duty cycle
  tim_oc_init.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
  TIM_OC1Init(TIM2, &tim_oc_init);

  // enable PWM output
  TIM_CCxCmd(TIM2, TIM_Channel_1, TIM_CCx_Enable);

  // start PWM
  TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
}

int main(void)
{
  init_ADC_PWM();

  while(1)
  {
    // wait for ADC injected conversion to complete
    while(!ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_JEOC));

    // read ADC injected conversion result
    uint16_t adc_value = ADC_GetInjectedConversionValue(ADC1, ADC_InjectedRank_1);

    // update PWM duty cycle based on ADC value
    TIM_SetCompare1(TIM2, adc_value);
  }
}
```